# Multiple user role on registration

Tags: user-roles, user-registration

I have a gravity registration form which allows users to select which role they want "Mechanics", "Plumbing", "Electrics" , However is there away to also set it so all new users have an automatic secondary role? So upon Registration the role "Supplier" is also granted?

Thanks

Comment: There are plugins which allow to assign additional user roles on registration. Alternatively you can try to code something yourself, but to help you with that, you have to show what you have tried first.

Comment: How are you currently setting the initial role - are you using a plugin or doing it with action hooks in your own code?

Comment: I used Toolset to create the additional roles and Gravity forms to allow them to pick their role.
I have tried a few plugins like role editor and multiples, but they dont quite do what I need, Just need it so upon registration there is a secondary role attached to the user. If that makes sense?

Comment: I did try to follow this https://www.role-editor.com/add-secondary-role-new-registered-user/ but it did not work

Comment: Try the comments on this thread:  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/assign-role-on-registration/